# Passing parameters to a modal from anchor tag href using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to pass 2 parameters into a modal box using codeigniter but aint getting it right. 
In a nutshell, what i am trying to achieve on the modal box is to select all from a table(mark) where student_id = $student_id and exam_id = $exam_id

$student_id and exam_id are the parameters passed from the onclick attribute of the anchor tag of student_marksheet.php

student_marksheet.php goes thus

```php
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showAjaxModal('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?modal/popup/modal_principal_comment/<?php echo $student_id;?>/<?php echo $row2['exam_id'];?>');">
    <i class="entypo-user"></i>
    <?php echo get_phrase('headmistress_comment');?>
</a>
```

this is my attempted means of getting the paramenters on the modal box but this way i can only catch one parameter.

```php
$edit_data = $this->db->get_where('mark', array('exam_id' => $param2) )->result_array();
```

How can i catch the two please

Comment: Codeigniter has a routing system to retrieve the parameters from urls  may this can be helpfull [https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html]

Comment: The links says file not found......

Comment: you right there is a ]  at the end of url , the right link is the following https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Good. Thanks.... I am able to access the site now